# Weird issue with CSS class

Tags: css, wordpress

i have one little but very weird CSS issue with my personal site. I found one CSS glitch on one button into my account page from Woocommerce.

[image]

when check CSS for that button, i found this class that use that settings:

```
.woocommerce a.button, .woocommerce-page a.button, .woocommerce button.button, .woocommerce-page button.button, .woocommerce input.button, .woocommerce-page input.button, .woocommerce #respond input#submit, .woocommerce-page #respond input#submit, .woocommerce #content input.button, .woocommerce-page #content input.button {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 background: #fff !important;
 box-shadow: none;
```

}

if i untick `background: #fff !important;` then button is back to normal look. I searched everywhere to find that CSS class, but looks like that class dont exist.. How to find where is posted that CSS and modify the class. This is test logins if someone want to check , because issue is not visible without login.

User = test
Pass = test5
URL

Any help?

Comment: Can you fiddle it?

Comment: Sharing the username and password won't help without sharing the URL of the site. ;-)

Comment: Not exactly. Its wordpress woocommerce site..

Comment: @Gacci, there's your answer, just above my comment :).

Comment: Its https://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/ sorry. Aftere login jst go to : https://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/my-account/edit-account/ and will see button issue.

Answer (score 1):

The style that you have identified is the one that causes the trouble. It is not present in an external stylesheet. Instead, it has been added inline. You may view it by `Right click -> View Source`.

To modify the style, either look in the custom styles added from the `Appearance > Customize > Additional Styles` or in the theme's `header.php` file and make the necessary changes.

Comment: Hi, checked into Additional Styles, and in header.php but that css rule not found there.

Comment: In that case, you may need to check the other PHP files in the theme and the plugins, starting with the `functions.php` file

Comment: checked functions.php . There in no any CSS !